# Relative paths in an ASP.NET application code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Being new to ASP.NET I'm unsure of the best solution to my problem.  I have a line of code like:

```
xDoc.Load("Templates/template1.cfg");
```

xDoc is an `XmlDocument`.  In my project, at the top level there is a directory called Templates.  When I run the project in debug mode, I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException`, and apparently it's looking for the Templates dir in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Templates`.

How can correctly point to that directory without hardcoding it?

Comment: Have you looked at `Server.MapPath` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` - returns the path of the relative path; `~` ensures the relative path is related to the application root

```
xDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Templates/template.cfg"));
```

Answer (score 12):

I would probably use

```
xDoc.Load(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Templates", "Template.cfg"));
```

This makes your XML loading code independent of ASP.NET.  If you were to reuse it in, say, a Windows Forms application, this would give a path relative to the directory containing the Windows Forms exectuable.

Answer (score 3):

```
xDoc.Load("~/Templates/template.cfg");
```

might work?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
xDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Templates/template1.cfg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a tilde "~" in your path.

```
xDoc.Load("~/Templates/template1.cfg");
```

The tilde represents the base directory for your application.

Comment: Unfortunately that was what I tried first, with the same problem.  Which is odd because ~/ works fine in the aspx pages.

Comment: Yeah - xDoc won't know it's being used in the context of an ASP.NET app. Check out Server.MapPath.